# Multi Core programming in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, processor

I am trying to write a computationally intensive program for android device in Java. Is there a way in which we can exploit different cores of processor in Android to boost the speed of our program ?
Links to some useful articles will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer http://alsutton.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/multi-core-android-101/
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Comment: Can't you just use threads and let the OS take care of it?

Comment: Threads don't have NEARLY as much power as a low level operation, its WAY faster.

Comment: Writing multi-threading applications has always been stressful. This article may help get you on the road.  [Managing Threads in Android](http://coopsoft.com/ar/AndroidArticle.html)

Comment: Anybody who wants to go down this road should be familiar with the issues in http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html .

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could look into is Renderscript.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html

from the dev site:

> Renderscript provides a platform-independent computation engine that
>   operates at the native level. Use it to accelerate your apps that
>   require extensive computational horsepower.

Comment: oh !! it's gr8, but how can I use it to find inverse of a 8x8 matrix that is being the bottleneck of my code. Current code that I am using is plain Java code and taking too much time to run.

Comment: That has to be some research on your part, I'm not 100 percent sure.

Comment: I went through documentation and other article on rederscript it doesn't seem to be very helpful. Is there some way by which I can take advantage of multiple-cores of Android processor. Like exploiting GPU and something like CUDA ?